# What are some impressive economics models with very high explained variance?

Tags: econometrics

I'll start with some examples.

[State-level analysis of variation in infant mortality rate: A socio-ecological approach](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/dissertations/AAI1573760/)

73% of infant mortality explained in the US by just a few variables.

[Exponential correlation of IQ and the wealth of nations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.gwern.net/docs/iq/2006-dickerson.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj9gO_KmYjLAhUU5WMKHeEsAksQFgglMAI&usg=AFQjCNGqXWhzJNdBO-UV0d4MCpFMIGc7rg&sig2=t_fWwesSjpEt_iqNISipnw)

69% of GDP per capita explained by IQ.

[Estimating Suicide Rates in Nations that Do Not Report Suicide Statistics](https://www.kon.org/urc/v8/zambrano.html)

78% of variance in suicide rates explained in Model 2, table 3.

What are some more examples of models with a lot of explanatory power for large scale social phenomena?

Comment: What exactly constitutes _"impressive"_ and _"very high"_?

Comment: I dunno. .......

Comment: Then I suppose my point will be clear; the question is difficult to answer and its quality questionable given the degree of ambiguity.